# JOOQ parsing issue postgres bitwise and (&)

Tags: jooq

I have a postgres SQL where

```
case when (column1 & 64) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end as aliasxyz
```

It's throwing `Caused by: org.jooq.impl.ParserException: Token ')' expected:`

Comment: See also the answer to your crosspost here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14813

Answer (score 0):

The problem at this point (jOOQ 3.18) is to find a way to correctly handle the disagreement about operator precedence among all the SQL dialects and encode that in a more powerful version of the parser. See:

- [#12339](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12339) Add support for parsing custom operators in ParseListener
- [#14683](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14683) Add parser support for infix bitwise operations